# Offseting div margin after centering it

Tags: html, css

I have a div centered in another div with:

```
<div id="align" style = "width: 420px; margin:auto; ">
```

The div stays always in the center and that's fine but,

how do I offset it 60px (or any other distance) to the right?

Comment: You could try `padding`

Comment: Or you could try left

Comment: nope. It's doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `div` and still have it centered using `position:relative`

```css
#align {
    width: 420px; 
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="align"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `relative position` and `left`, for example:

```
<div id="align" style="width: 420px; margin:auto; position: relative; left: 60px;">
```